# class number for special cyclotomic fields

Tags: cyclotomic-fields

Are the class number of the cyclotomic fields $Q(\mu_n)$ known, where $n=2^k$ ?  Especially for $k=12$ ?
Such fields are often used in Post Quantum cryptography,  e.g. in Ring Learning With Errors systems.

Comment: You mean $n=2^{2048}$? Seems rather big...

Comment: That was a mistake, thanks!